# Leaflet: Change default title length

Tags: leaflet

I'm using leaflet to show vehicle marker with a title:

```
boatMarker = L.vehicleMarker([val.lat, val.lon],
                            { color: val.color, title: val.name, active: val.active })
                            .addTo(map);
```

In my case, the vehicle name could be very long like "MH-AB 1234, car type, car model (123456789, xyz)" and when showing the name in the map, I just see the middle part like "e, car model (". Is it possible to increase the lenght of the shown title?

Comment: Screenshot and a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please.

Comment: Also explicitly specifying the plugins that you use would surely help.

Comment: I found the setting. It wasn't in leaflet but in canvas drawing. Thanks!